# Using OAUTH Bearer Token on Flask-Appbuilder REST endpoints

Tags: python, flask, oauth, bearer-token, flask-appbuilder

Is it possible to somehow configure Flask-Appbuilder so that its [REST API](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickhowto.html?highlight=rest#rest-api) would accept Authorization header containing Bearer {my_token} in it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you meant by Flask-Appbuilders api ?

Comment: @GeorgeJPadayatti I mean the api described [here](http://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickhowto.html?highlight=rest#rest-api). I'll update the question as well.

Comment: Some update ? how did you do it ?